# Corpus suggestion for financial domain

Tags: dataset, finance, annotation

I am looking for a financial corpus or any form of publicly available financial texts which is replete with technical terms and acronyms.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/